# Detecting changes to arrays with RivetsJS

Tags: javascript, rivets.js

I'm a new user of [RivetsJS](http://rivetsjs.com/) and am trying to figure out how to get my bindings to refresh when array elements are *modified*. It seems like Rivets is able to detect changes to non-complex variables when simple assignments are used (i.e. `player_lives -= 1`). It also detects when I `push()` to a bound array. No refresh occurs when I assign a new value to an existing array element, though. Here's an example of what I'm trying:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rivets/0.8.1/rivets.bundled.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var numbers = [111, 222, 333];

        window.addEventListener('load', function() {
            rivets.bind(document.getElementById('numbers'), {numbers: numbers});
        });

        function changeNum() {
            numbers[0] = 5;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="changeNum()">Add a number</button>
    <div id="numbers">{ numbers }</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this case the `{ numbers }` binding is not refreshed and the original values continue to display. I suspect that Rivets isn't able to detect that the change is occurring, but I'm not sure what the best approach to take to remedy that would be. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can I ask why you choose rivets.js against angular?

Comment: I'm not opposed to Angular but in this case I'm trying to teach something that abstracts away as much of the MVC inner workings as possible and Rivets is very simple from that perspective, esp. compared to Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems rivets can't detect the changes to indexes of an array.

However, it does detect when the reference to array changes.

So one solution is to *trigger* a reference change, in your example, something like

```
function changeNum() {
  //numbers[0] = 5;
  numbers = [5].concat(numbers.slice(1)); // [5, 222, 333]
}
```

Will trigger an update

Comment: Yeah unfortunately you're right; see a response from the developers here: https://github.com/mikeric/rivets/issues/520. In the response Ben suggests push()'ing new elements on but the idea is the same as what you're suggesting here.